# pair arrays elements with min difference matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two arrays 1x4 'x' and 'y'. I want to find which 'combination of elements 'paired' between these two arrays' will give minimum difference(elements of array are angles). I want to find WHICH elements should be paired to get that minimum. I do not care for the result minimum itself. I tried using indexing but didn't get anywhere.

Example:

```
x=[x1 x2 x3 x4], y=[y1 y2 y3 y4].  
x=[ 295 10 25 18 ], y=[ 200   290   245   326]
```

I get minimum angle difference between x and y 'xyMin' from here:
[Calculating absolute differences between two angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276369/calculating-absolute-differences-between-two-angles/32276370)

```
xyMin=  [ 95    80   140    52];
```

This is the minimum difference between angle elements of the 2 arrays. However, I want to know WHICH elements of the arrays were paired to give this minimum. So I need to get something like:
    [Example]

```
xyArrayElementsThatGiveMinCombination:  [x1-y3, x2-y4, x3-y1, x4-y2].
```

EDITED:

I want to clarify that I want to find WHICH element of 'x' to pair with which element of 'y' so that difference between angles is minimum . i.e. x[1 2 3 4]-y[1 2 3 4] will give minimum. If there are more than one combinations that give same minimum choose first.

SORRY I REALIZE IT IS CONFUSING!
thank a lot for help!

Comment: why minus?at least please comment for my learning.

Comment: Start by actually assigning values to your arrays x and y, and why this combination is not the combination you are looking for. This namely looks like a fine line of code.

Comment: I've just edited. Thank you for the input

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You want to find the minimum difference between all value-pairs of x and y?

Comment: @RobertStettler Please see edited question. I want to find which elements of X should be paired with which elements of y to get best minimum..I don't care for the minimum difference itself..

Comment: But that is always the same solution, no matter which pairing you chose (linear), or do you take `abs` at some point?

Comment: @RobertStettler. Sorry yes it is angle values so i take abs values.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you it is "for two vectors x and y, find the permutation vector p for which distance(x,y(p)) is minimal". Could you add distance as a piece of matlab code to your question?

Comment: @Daniel. Yes I probably need p. but not values of p. But p =[x[n]-y[n]]..i have just edited my question again with better example i hope..

Comment: The function is probably not doing what you want. `abs(180-x-180)` is `abs(x)`

Comment: I tried using 'mod' but it gives 355 difference between 290 and 295. while it is 5 degrees I am for..

Comment: The only way I can think of now is to disregard the minimum difference value and do check in loop. That will keep indices' combination of arrays elements with the minimum difference..

Comment: @mil: It was a little to much to fit into a comment. Code to calculate the difference between angles is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276369/calculating-absolute-differences-between-two-angles/32276370). I think this is what you want to minimize.

Comment: @mil: I think you should try to rephrase your question now and make clear what you want to minimize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88258/discussion-between-mil-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically [RobertSettlers solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268425/pair-arrays-elements-with-min-difference-matlab?noredirect=1#), but using the distance metric which is now clear from the discussion, a simple brute force approac:

```
x=x(:);
y=y(:);
Y=perms(y);
[distance,I]=min(sum(bsxfun(absDiffDeg,x,Y.'),1));
best_permuted_y=Y(I,:);
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. So neat and concise too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this here (if it really solves your problem)

```
[v,i] = min(sum(abs(perms(y)-repmat(x, factorial(4), 1)), 2))
```

Then you get `v` the min value and `i` the index of that particular min value (the first one)

> ATTENTION: if the size is larger than 10 entries (for one vector), then the permutation takes over 3 gigs!

Answer (score 1):

This is another Idea how to solve the problem. I am not absolutely sure if it always produces the correct result. It is based on a assumption:

> An optimal solution can created sorting both x and y, then circular shifting y.

If this is true, this solution is much better, but I am not sure if this is true.

```
x=x(:);
y=y(:);
%Sort both vector to reduce the problem to the simplified case
[sorted_x,index_x]=sort(x);
[sorted_y,index_y]=sort(y);
distance=nan(1,numel(x));
%circular shift, try all combinations
for shift=1:numel(x)
    distance(shift)=sum(absDiffDeg(circshift(sorted_x,shift),sorted_y));
end
%get the best shift
[minimal_distance,shift]=min(distance);
%Now a solution is fond permuting both x and y, the permutations for x and y are:
%circshift(index_x,shift) and index_y
%but permuting x is unnessecary. Undo the permutation of x and keep the paris between x and y
[~,reverse_x]=sort(circshift(index_x,shift));
%Best permutation for y
y_permutation=index_y(reverse_x);
%permute y
y_permuted=y(y_permutation);
```