# Calculating absolute differences between two angles

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, angle

I have two angles a and b, I want to calculate the absolute difference between both angles. Examples

```
>> absDiffDeg(360,5)
ans = 5
>> absDiffDeg(-5,5)
ans = 10
>> absDiffDeg(5,-5)
ans = 10
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normalize the difference, abs operation is not necessary because mod(x,y) takes the sign of y.

```
normDeg = mod(a-b,360);
```

This will be a number between 0-360, but we want the smallest angle which is between 0-180. Easiest way to get this is

```
absDiffDeg = min(360-normDeg, normDeg);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about unsing unwrap ? Here is a try:

```
absDiffDeg = @(a,b) abs(diff(unwrap([a,b]/180*pi)*180/pi));
```

Best,

Answer (score 3):

When doing math with angles, it is useful to normalize them first. This function normalizes all angles to a (-180,180] range:

```
 normalizeDeg=@(x)(-mod(-x+180,360)+180)
```

Now having this function to normalize, the absolute difference can be calculated:

```
absDiffDeg=@(a,b)abs(normalizeDeg(normalizeDeg(a)-normalizeDeg(b)))
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, took me a while to understand it though :P. One way to simplify it would be to define normalize differently, to 0-360, rather than -180-180. `normalizeDeg=@(x)(mod(x,360))` This is less standard, but also solves the problem

Comment: You are right, the code could be simplified further. Also the normalisation of inputs is not necessary here, but typically good practice as it simplifies testing.